# NHibernate many-to-many criteria

Tags: .net, nhibernate

I have entity **Problem** mapped using *many-to-many* to entity **Tag** (Problem has a list of tags). I want to load all the **Problems**, which have specific **Tags**.
*For example:*
Problem1 (tag1)
Problem2 (tag1, tag2)
Problem3 (tag1, tag3)
Problem4 (tag3, tag4)
*I want to get the problems by filter "tag1, tag2". The system shall return:*
Problem1 (tag1)
Problem2 (tag1, tag2)
Problem3 (tag1, tag3)
I have been puzzling over this problem for a week already. Have you any ideas?
*P.S. Load all the list and filter it using LINQ is the last possible variant...*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HQL is a better fit for these queries than Criteria.

One possible solution:

```
session.CreateQuery(@"select distinct p
                      from Problem p
                      join p.Tags t
                      where t in (:tags)")
       .SetParameterList("tags", listOfTags)
```

Comment: Can I use HQL query and criteria together? The matter is I need paging too (SetFirstResult() and SetMaxResult()).

Comment: HQL and Criteria are different methods. But you can use SetFirstResult and SetMaxResult on HQL queries too.