# Teneo ignores mappedBy in OneToMany and created ForeignKey

Tags: hibernate, nhibernate, many-to-many, hibernate-mapping, teneo

I am trying to follow [this example](http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-many-to-many-example-join-table-extra-column-annotation/) and create a many to many relation in model in a separate table with composite key and additional columns using Teneo. My model is in hibernate and this is what the ecore file like for the part of model:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ecore:EPackage xmi:version="2.0" xmlns:xmi="http://www.omg.org/XMI" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:ecore="http://www.eclipse.org/emf/2002/Ecore" name="my" nsURI="test.my" nsPrefix="test">
  <eClassifiers xsi:type="ecore:EClass" name="Resource">
    <eAnnotations source="teneo.jpa">
      <details key="appinfo" value="@Table(uniqueConstraints={@UniqueConstraint(columnNames={&quot;ip&quot;,&quot;name&quot;, &quot;revision&quot;,  &quot;type&quot;})})"/>
    </eAnnotations>
    <eStructuralFeatures xsi:type="ecore:EAttribute" name="type" eType="ecore:EDataType http://www.eclipse.org/emf/2002/Ecore#//EString"/>
    <eStructuralFeatures xsi:type="ecore:EAttribute" name="name" eType="ecore:EDataType http://www.eclipse.org/emf/2002/Ecore#//EString"/>
    <eStructuralFeatures xsi:type="ecore:EAttribute" name="id" eType="ecore:EDataType http://www.eclipse.org/emf/2002/Ecore#//EInt"
        iD="true">
      <eAnnotations source="teneo.jpa">
        <details key="appinfo" value="@Id&#xD;&#xA;    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)"/>
      </eAnnotations>
    </eStructuralFeatures>
    <eStructuralFeatures xsi:type="ecore:EReference" name="resourceTags" ordered="false"
        upperBound="-1" eType="#//ResourceTag" resolveProxies="false" eOpposite="#//ResourceTag/resource">
      <eAnnotations source="teneo.jpa">
        <details key="appinfo" value="@OneToMany ( indexed = false, fetch=FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = &quot;resourceId&quot;,  cascade=CascadeType.ALL)"/>
      </eAnnotations>
    </eStructuralFeatures>
  </eClassifiers>
  <eClassifiers xsi:type="ecore:EClass" name="Tag">
    <eAnnotations source="teneo.jpa">
      <details key="appinfo" value="@Table(uniqueConstraints={@UniqueConstraint(columnNames={ &quot;name&quot;})})&#xD;&#xA;@NoAuditing"/>
    </eAnnotations>
    <eStructuralFeatures xsi:type="ecore:EAttribute" name="name" eType="ecore:EDataType http://www.eclipse.org/emf/2002/Ecore#//EString"/>
    <eStructuralFeatures xsi:type="ecore:EAttribute" name="id" eType="ecore:EDataType http://www.eclipse.org/emf/2002/Ecore#//EInt"
        iD="true">
      <eAnnotations source="teneo.jpa">
        <details key="appinfo" value="@Id&#xD;&#xA;    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)"/>
      </eAnnotations>
    </eStructuralFeatures>
    <eStructuralFeatures xsi:type="ecore:EReference" name="resourceTags" ordered="false"
        upperBound="-1" eType="#//ResourceTag" resolveProxies="false" eOpposite="#//ResourceTag/tag">
      <eAnnotations source="teneo.jpa">
        <details key="appinfo" value="@OneToMany (indexed=false, fetch=FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = &quot;pk.tagid&quot;, cascade=CascadeType.ALL)"/>
      </eAnnotations>
    </eStructuralFeatures>
  </eClassifiers>
  <eClassifiers xsi:type="ecore:EClass" name="ResourceTag">
    <eAnnotations source="teneo.jpa">
      <details key="appinfo" value="@Table(name = &quot;ResourceTag&quot;)&#xD;&#xA;"/>
    </eAnnotations>
    <eStructuralFeatures xsi:type="ecore:EAttribute" name="date" eType="ecore:EDataType http://www.eclipse.org/emf/2002/Ecore#//EDate"/>
    <eStructuralFeatures xsi:type="ecore:EReference" name="pk" eType="#//ResourceTagId"
        resolveProxies="false">
      <eAnnotations source="teneo.jpa">
        <details key="appinfo" value="@EmbeddedId"/>
      </eAnnotations>
    </eStructuralFeatures>
    <eStructuralFeatures xsi:type="ecore:EAttribute" name="comment" eType="ecore:EDataType http://www.eclipse.org/emf/2002/Ecore#//EString"/>
    <eStructuralFeatures xsi:type="ecore:EReference" name="tag" eType="#//Tag" eOpposite="#//Tag/resourceTags">
      <eAnnotations source="teneo.jpa">
        <details key="appinfo" value="@Transient"/>
      </eAnnotations>
    </eStructuralFeatures>
    <eStructuralFeatures xsi:type="ecore:EReference" name="resource" eType="#//Resource"
        eOpposite="#//Resource/resourceTags">
      <eAnnotations source="teneo.jpa">
        <details key="appinfo" value="@Transient"/>
      </eAnnotations>
    </eStructuralFeatures>
  </eClassifiers>
  <eClassifiers xsi:type="ecore:EClass" name="ResourceTagId">
    <eAnnotations source="teneo.jpa">
      <details key="appinfo" value="@Embeddable"/>
    </eAnnotations>
    <eStructuralFeatures xsi:type="ecore:EReference" name="tag" eType="#//Tag">
      <eAnnotations source="teneo.jpa">
        <details key="appinfo" value="@ManyToOne&#xD;&#xA;@JoinColumns({&#xD;&#xA;&#x9;@JoinColumn(name=&quot;tagId&quot;, referencedColumnName = &quot;id&quot;)&#xD;&#xA;})"/>
      </eAnnotations>
    </eStructuralFeatures>
    <eStructuralFeatures xsi:type="ecore:EReference" name="resource" eType="#//Resource">
      <eAnnotations source="teneo.jpa">
        <details key="appinfo" value="@ManyToOne&#xD;&#xA;@JoinColumns({&#xD;&#xA;&#x9;@JoinColumn(name=&quot;resourceId&quot;, referencedColumnName = &quot;id&quot;)&#xD;&#xA;})"/>
      </eAnnotations>
    </eStructuralFeatures>
  </eClassifiers>
</ecore:EPackage>
```

The generated mapping for this model is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN" "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-mapping auto-import="false">
    <typedef name="model.EIllegalStateException" class="org.eclipse.emf.teneo.hibernate.mapping.DefaultToStringUserType">
        <param name="epackage">http://www.qualcomm.com/qti/qsip/designbook/model</param>
        <param name="edatatype">EIllegalStateException</param>
    </typedef>
    <class name="test.my.ResourceImpl" entity-name="Resource" abstract="false" lazy="false" discriminator-value="Resource" table="`resource`">
        <meta attribute="eclassName" inherit="false">Resource</meta>
        <meta attribute="epackage" inherit="false">http://www.qualcomm.com/qti/qsip/designbook/model</meta>
        <id name="id" type="int" unsaved-value="0">
            <column not-null="true" unique="false" name="`id`"/>
            <generator class="native"/>
        </id>
        <discriminator type="string">
            <column name="`dtype`" index="resourcedtype" length="255" not-null="true"/>
        </discriminator>
        <version name="revision" type="int">
            <column not-null="true" unique="false" name="`revision`" unique-key="c0"/>
        </version>
        <property name="type" lazy="false" insert="true" update="true" not-null="false" unique="false" type="java.lang.String">
            <column not-null="false" unique="false" name="`type`" unique-key="c0"/>
        </property>
        <property name="name" lazy="false" insert="true" update="true" not-null="false" unique="false" type="java.lang.String">
            <column not-null="false" unique="false" name="`name`" unique-key="c0"/>
        </property>
        <bag name="resourceTags" inverse="true" lazy="false" cascade="all,delete-orphan">
            <key update="true">
                <column name="`resourcetag_resource_id`" unique="false"/>
            </key>
            <one-to-many entity-name="ResourceTag"/>
        </bag>
    </class>
    <class name="test.my.TagImpl" entity-name="Tag" abstract="false" lazy="false" discriminator-value="Tag" table="`tag`">
        <meta attribute="eclassName" inherit="false">Tag</meta>
        <meta attribute="epackage" inherit="false">http://www.qualcomm.com/qti/qsip/designbook/model</meta>
        <id name="id" type="int" unsaved-value="0">
            <column not-null="true" unique="false" name="`id`"/>
            <generator class="native"/>
        </id>
        <discriminator type="string">
            <column name="`dtype`" index="tagdtype" length="255" not-null="true"/>
        </discriminator>
        <property name="name" lazy="false" insert="true" update="true" not-null="false" unique="false" type="java.lang.String">
            <column not-null="false" unique="false" name="`name`" unique-key="c0"/>
        </property>
        <bag name="resourceTags" inverse="true" lazy="false" cascade="all,delete-orphan">
            <key update="true">
                <column name="`resourcetag_tag_id`" unique="false"/>
            </key>
            <one-to-many entity-name="ResourceTag"/>
        </bag>
    </class>
    <class name="test.my.ResourceTagImpl" entity-name="ResourceTag" abstract="false" lazy="false" discriminator-value="ResourceTag" table="`resourcetag`">
        <meta attribute="eclassName" inherit="false">ResourceTag</meta>
        <meta attribute="epackage" inherit="false">http://www.qualcomm.com/qti/qsip/designbook/model</meta>
        <composite-id name="pk" class="test.my.ResourceTagIdImpl" access="org.eclipse.emf.teneo.hibernate.mapping.property.EReferencePropertyHandler">
            <meta attribute="eclassName" inherit="false">ResourceTagId</meta>
            <meta attribute="epackage" inherit="false">http://www.qualcomm.com/qti/qsip/designbook/model</meta>
            <key-many-to-one name="tag" entity-name="Tag" lazy="false">
                <column not-null="false" unique="false" name="`tagid`"/>
            </key-many-to-one>
            <key-many-to-one name="resource" entity-name="Resource" lazy="false">
                <column not-null="false" unique="false" name="`resourceid`"/>
            </key-many-to-one>
        </composite-id>
        <discriminator type="string">
            <column name="`dtype`" index="ResourceTagdtype" length="255" not-null="true"/>
        </discriminator>
        <property name="date" lazy="false" insert="true" update="true" not-null="false" unique="false" type="timestamp">
            <column not-null="false" unique="false" name="`date`"/>
        </property>
        <property name="comment" lazy="false" insert="true" update="true" not-null="false" unique="false" type="java.lang.String">
            <column not-null="false" unique="false" name="`comment`"/>
        </property>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

As you can see the oneToMany mapping from Resource to ResourceTag is mapped by a new foreignkey, as a result of this the ResourceTag table has repeated columns named `resourcetag_tag_id` and `resourcetag_resource_id` other than the ones in the composite primary key 'resourceId' and 'tagid'.

My hibernate perisitent options are following:

```
props.setProperty(PersistenceOptions.CASCADE_POLICY_ON_NON_CONTAINMENT,
                "PERSIST,REFRESH");
props.setProperty(PersistenceOptions.CASCADE_POLICY_ON_CONTAINMENT,
                "ALL");

props.setProperty(PersistenceOptions.MAP_ALL_LISTS_AS_IDBAG, "false");
props.setProperty(PersistenceOptions.ALWAYS_MAP_LIST_AS_BAG, "false");

props.setProperty(PersistenceOptions.ID_FEATURE_AS_PRIMARY_KEY, "false");
props.setProperty(PersistenceOptions.ALWAYS_VERSION, "false");
props.setProperty(PersistenceOptions.JOIN_TABLE_FOR_NON_CONTAINED_ASSOCIATIONS, "false");
props.setProperty(PersistenceOptions.SET_FOREIGN_KEY_NAME, "false");
props.setProperty(PersistenceOptions.FEATUREMAP_AS_COMPONENT, "true");
```

I have tried many different combinations in the mappedby attribute of @OnetoMany relation in the resource.resourceTags but all of them are ignored by teneo/hibernate. I also tried to use the @AssociationOverride as explained in the example, but that didn't have any effect on the mapping either.

What I want to achieve a bidirectional many-to-many relation between tag and resource which has some extra attributes. So that, when I loaded the resource I can automatically get the tags and when I load the tag I can automatically get the resources. However, with this mapping the extra foreign key columns in the ResourceTag table are null and the relation doesn't get fetched as a result.

This is a subset of the model and many other references are included in these classes that I removed. Many of the configurations are defined based on teh other requirements.

Comment: Before you get some answer, I'd like *(have to)* descourage you from `many-to-many`. Mostly if you plan to keep some information related to that relation/pairing object. Try to check these:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22563082/, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15510748/. Also you can check here how powerful and complex queries we can build if we avoid manyToMany: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23772548/

Comment: I am actually doing the same thing basically and creating the link class where two classes have one-to-many association with it. However, I have still problem with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using joinColumn instead of mappedby actually solved the problem. You can fin dmore info [here](https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/m/1393439/#msg_1393439).