# NHibernate fully populate a partially loaded collection

Tags: c#, nhibernate, linq-to-nhibernate, queryover

I have a schema with `Project` objects. Each Project has an owner, and an additional collection of `SharePermission` objects detailing other users that can also access the Project. SharePermissions point to a more detailed user object of type `IdentityUser`

In this case, I load an `IEnumerable` of `Projects` using the method:

```
 /// <summary>
 /// Gets a collection of projects that a user id has access to view.
 /// </summary>
 public static IEnumerable<Project> GetVisibleByUserFuture(ISession session, int userId)
 {
     Project p = null;
     ProjectShare s = null;
     IdentityUser u = null;
     return session.QueryOver<Project>(() => p)
         .Left.JoinAlias(() => p.SharePermissions
                , () => s                // Only join when we are not owner
                , Restrictions.On(() => p.OwnerId).Not.IsIn(new [] { userId }))
         .Left.JoinAlias(() => s.User, () => u)
         .Where(() => s.User.UserId == userId || p.OwnerId == userId)
         .Future();
 }
```

You will notice that the `SharePermissions` part had a restriction on the join so only part of that collection is loaded.

Later on I want to pick a single `Project` from that previously loaded IEnumerable collection and load the full `SharePermissions` collection without restriction.

I am not entirely sure how I'm meant to do that.
Do I just load a whole new `Project` object again?
Or can I re-use the existing `Project` object and somehow tell NH to fully populate the SharePermissions collection?

Comment: Might want to try `NhibernateUtil.Initialize(p.SharePermissions)` but I think it only works on proxy objects, not partially loaded collections.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution in this case would be **`session.Refresh(project)`**. As documented here:

- [9.2. Loading an object](http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#manipulatingdata-loading) *(small cite)*

> It is possible to re-load an object and all its collections at any time, using the Refresh() method. This is useful when database triggers are used to initialize some of the properties of the object.

```
...
session.Refresh(project);
```

*But I would suggest to change the query. Select just a root entity Project, use subquery to filter it, apply batch fetching for collection loading*

check these links for batch fetching and subquery examples:

- [batch fetching overview](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20970816/1679310)
- [subquery example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20528760/)
- [NHibernate - Many to Many Query using Junction/Joiner Table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23772548/)