# Rename NHibernate criteria

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I am trying to join aliases multiple times but it depends on the number of times it should do it.

```
Employee employeeAlias = null;
Thing thingAlias = null;
var names = string[] {"A", "B", "C", "D", "E"} // number of values could vary
for(int i = 0; i < names.Length ; i++)
{
   queryOver
       .JoinAlias(() => employeeAlias.Things, 
                  () => thingAlias,
                  JoinType.LeftOuterJoin, 
                  Restrictions.Eq(Projections.Property(() => thingAlias.Name, 
                                  names[i]));
}
```

However, upon execution, NHibernate throws an error saying:

`NHibernate.QueryException: duplicate alias: thingAlias ---> System.ArgumentException: An item with the same key has already been added`

Is there a way I can make NHibernate join an alias with a specified name so that it will not re-use the name of the variable?

Thanks guys. This has been my problem since yesterday and I can't find a proper solution.

PS:

I'm trying to do something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM Employee e
LEFT OUTER JOIN Thing t on e.Id = t.EmployeedId AND t.Name = "A"
LEFT OUTER JOIN Thing t on e.Id = t.EmployeedId AND t.Name = "B"
```

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to achieve is impossible. Each relation (`many-to-one`, `one-to-many`) can be used exactly once.

To support this statement, please, check it here: [CriteriaQueryTranslator.cs](https://github.com/nhibernate/nhibernate-core/blob/master/src/NHibernate/Loader/Criteria/CriteriaQueryTranslator.cs#L290)

```
private void CreateAssociationPathCriteriaMap()
{
    foreach (CriteriaImpl.Subcriteria crit in rootCriteria.IterateSubcriteria())
    {
        string wholeAssociationPath = GetWholeAssociationPath(crit);
        try
        {
            associationPathCriteriaMap.Add(wholeAssociationPath, crit);
        }
        catch (ArgumentException ae)
        {
            throw new QueryException("duplicate association path: "
                                    + wholeAssociationPath, ae);
        }
```

So, what we can see here, regardless of aliases, at the end, all associtated relations (JOINS) are added into `associationPathCriteriaMap`, which is `IDictionary<string, ICriteria>`.

That means, that there is now way how to have two same keys in play...

Comment: please take a look at my last edit.. do you have any idea on how i can do it in nhibernate? The reason I asked my question earlier is because I thought that way was the correct way of achieving my desired sql script.

Comment: I would say, the only, or **the** way is to map more collections to the same table. And you would need to use WHERE to filter them. I mean to have Things1, Things2, Things3 and then you can join them as required. Check http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#collections-mapping attribute `where`

Comment: but does it mean i will be hardcoding it?
the number of joins is dynamic. cant hardcode things1, things2, things3.. :(

Comment: Exactly. But this is **the** solution with NHibernate. That's how it was designed. If you want to get something into query 1) relation must exist 2) can be used only once. BUT I would say, that **the question** is: why you need that? for filtering? then you should change the approach and use `I.` subqueries (you can have lot of them) and then filter the `II.` root query with their results... Maybe check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/23905744/1679310 where I show how to use Subqueries ... really heavily ;)

Comment: kind of. i want to check if the rows contains a certain value in the name colum. that is why i am using a left outer join for each of those values.

Comment: Subquery is the answer. Search how to, you will get functionality you need. I am sure...

Answer (score 0):

I didn't tried this but I think instead of using `for-loop` and `Restrictions.Eq`, we can (not sure, but in case you didn't tried it) use `Restrictions.In` like-

```
Restrictions.In(Projections.Property(() => thingAlias.Name, names));
```

Comment: Nope. I want to project into a column each name :(