# How can I make a query that returns objects who contain all ids from list

Tags: list, nhibernate, hql, where-clause, queryover

I have two objects : Profile and Tags. Each profile can contain multiple tags. On my search page I can select multiple tags to search on. Now I want a query that get all profiles that have all the selected tags.

So if I use `WhereRestrictionOn().IsIn()` I get profiles which contains at least 1 of the tags but I need to return profiles which contains all the tags in the list.

I also tried multiple Where conditions for each selected tag but then I get no results at all.

I have no clue how to do this any help is much appreciated!

> **Structure:**
>
> Profile : Id
>
> ProfileTag : ProfileId, TagId
>
> Tag: Id

**Mapping Profile**

```
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2" namespace="Agrolink.Application.Models" assembly="Agrolink.Application">
  <class name="Agrolink.Application.Models.Profile" lazy="false" table="Profiles" >

    <id name="Id" column="Id"  >
      <generator class="identity" />
    </id>

    <bag name="Tags" table="ProfileTags" cascade="all-delete-orphan" inverse="true">
      <key column="IdProfile" not-null="true"/>
      <one-to-many class="Agrolink.Application.Models.ProfileTag"  />
    </bag>

  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

**Mapping ProfileTag**

```
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2" namespace="Agrolink.Application.Models" assembly="Agrolink.Application">
  <class name="Agrolink.Application.Models.ProfileTag" lazy="false" table="ProfileTags" >

    <id name="Id" column="Id"  >
      <generator class="identity" />
    </id>

    <many-to-one name="Profile" class="Agrolink.Application.Models.Profile" column="IdProfile" cascade="save-update" />
    <many-to-one name="Tag" class="Agrolink.Application.Models.Tag" column="IdTag" cascade="none" />

  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

**Mapping Tag**

```
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2" namespace="Agrolink.Application.Models" assembly="Agrolink.Application">
  <class name="Agrolink.Application.Models.Tag" lazy="false" table="Tags" >

    <id name="Id" column="Id"  >
      <generator class="identity" />
    </id>

    <property name="Name" column="Name" />
    <property name="Type"  type="Agrolink.Application.Models.TagType, Agrolink.Application"  column="IdType" />

    <many-to-one name="Parent" class="Agrolink.Application.Models.Tag" column="IdParent" cascade="none" />

    <bag name="Children" table="Tags" cascade="all" inverse="true">
      <key column="IdParent" not-null="true"/>
      <one-to-many class="Agrolink.Application.Models.Tag"  />
    </bag>

  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

**SubQuery to achieve this (Solution):**

```
        Profile p = null;
        Account a = null;
        Institute i = null;

        var q = Session.QueryOver(() => p)
            .JoinAlias(x => x.Account, () => a)
            .JoinAlias(x => x.Institute, () => i)
            .Where(x => x.Type == ProfileType.Expert && x.Status == ProfileStatus.Active);

        if(_keywordIds.Any())
            foreach (var keywordId in _keywordIds)
            {
                Tag t = null;

                var subQ = QueryOver.Of<ProfileTag>()
                    .JoinAlias(pt => pt.Tag, () => t)
                    .Where(() => t.Id == keywordId)
                    .Select(pt => pt.Profile.Id);           

                q.WithSubquery.WhereProperty(() => p.Id).In(subQ);
            }

        if (_institute != null) q.Where(() => i.Id == _institute);

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(_name)) q.Where(Restrictions.Disjunction()
                    .Add(Restrictions.Like("a.FirstName", _name + "%"))
                    .Add(Restrictions.Like("a.LastName", _name + "%"))
                );

        return (PagedList<Profile>) q.List<Profile>().ToPagedList(_page, _itemsPerPage);
```

Comment: *You would need a subquery. Check this http://stackoverflow.com/q/23772548/1679310*

Comment: This looks good @RadimKöhler but I am having trouble with this line : query.WithSubquery
        .WhereProperty(() => file.id)
        .In(subQueryForAttribute);

I am not sure what to put in the WhereProperty. The object structure is in the question.

Comment: @RadimKöhler My mapping is almost the same as in the example you linked me. I can add it aswell in the question.

Comment: Wow, that is totally different scenario. It is not many to many - you have **"the right mapping"** ... so it should be easy... If you still do not think you can use that solution, I'd try to draft that...

Comment: I posted my query in the answer. Could you check it please? Thx!

Comment: Nanou, I think I found the issue. I (without check in real app) tried to adjust your snippet to show what should be changed. There could be some typos, but the essence of it should be clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is almost it, but we need so called Detached QueryOver, which we will get with construction `QueryOver.Of`

```
foreach (var keywordId in _keywordIds)
{
    //Tag t = null;

    var subQ = QueryOver.Of<ProfileTag>()
        //.JoinAlias(pt => pt.Tag, () => t)
        //.Where(() => t.Id == keywordId)
        .Where(x => x.Tag.Id == keywordId)
        //.Select(pt => t.Id);           
        .Select(pt => pt.Profile.Id);          

    q.WithSubquery.WhereProperty(() => p.Id).In(subQ);
}
```

Comment: Hmm, I am still having problems. Its not returning any results. I seem to get a nullexception on the Select of the subquery.

Comment: Could you share your latest attempt? adjust the quesiton

Comment: Updated the subquery in question.

Comment: I tried locally, with my entities (replacing yours in feasible way) and with updated foreach... it should work

Comment: Yes! I also figured out what was wrong. Thank you very much for all the help!

Comment: I am so glad to see, that .. NHibernate still can do some good job for someone... Enjoy it, sir ;)